# Report is running slow, Need step i should check to make it faster . Any idea on troubleshooting Code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am mostly working on central application. Have to jump into fix back end server issue. I have a report running on SQL Server, taking bit of time, I have attached the code. I need some help in how should I investigate this issue step by step. The issue is not with hardware. I already checked with sysadmin

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Patinet_Model]
    @mid_pat UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @m_tblpat dbo.GuidList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @trtnum TABLE 
    ( 
        pid INT NOT NULL,
        Oid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE(sid, Oid)
    );

    DECLARE @trtper TABLE 
    ( 
        pid INT NOT NULL,
        Oid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        patgusBIT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE(sid, Oid)
    );

    WITH Sbb AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ug.[smid] ORDER BY aa.vnum) AS rownumber,
            aa.pid, 
            aa.Oid,
            ug.[smid] as sid
        FROM 
            dbo.pat_note aa
        JOIN 
            dbo.[pat_note] ug ON aa.GroupId = ug.[group_id]
                              AND ug.[is_hidden] = 0
        JOIN 
            @m_tblpat cc ON aa.Oid = cc.item
        WHERE 
            aa.communityid = @mid_pat
    )
    INSERT INTO @trtnum (pid, Oid, sid)
        SELECT pid, Oid,  sid
        FROM Sbb
        WHERE rownumber = 1;

    INSERT INTO @trtper (pid, Oid, sid, patgusBIT)
        SELECT 
            aa.pid, aa.Oid, aa.sid, 
            CASE WHEN ee.sid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM 
            dbo.pat_note aa
        JOIN 
            @m_tblpat dd ON aa.Oid = dd.item
                         AND aa.sid IS NOT NULL
        LEFT JOIN 
            @trtnum ee ON aa.sid = ee.sid AND aa.Oid = ee.Oid
        WHERE 
            aa.communityid = @mid_pat;


    INSERT INTO @trtper (pid, Oid, sid, patgusBIT)
        SELECT pid, Oid, sid, 0 AS patgusBIT
        FROM @trtnum ff
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @trtper WHERE sid = ff.sid AND Oid = ff.Oid);

    WITH CTEA AS
    (
        SELECT
            pkOid AS OG,
            s_g
        FROM ct.oj o
        JOIN @m_tblpat t
            ON o.pkOid = t.item
    )
    SELECT 
        s.pid, 
        s.Oid, 
        s.vnum, 
        s.sid, 
        s.GroupID,
        s.communityid,
        s.Dt_Created as createddate,
        s.[Dt_Modified] as modifieddate,
        us.sid as groupsbb_sid, 
        us.overridesGroupSbbscription,
        u.[User_ID] AS u_sid, 
        u.UserNamespace AS u_namespace, 
        u.FName AS u_fname, 
        u.LName AS u_lname, 
        u.StatusText AS u_statusText, 
        u.StatusUpdated AS u_statusUpdated, 
        u.IMAGE AS u_hasImage, 
        isImageShared AS u_isImageShared, 
        u.Status AS u_status,
        GETDATE() AS u_lastvisit, 
        @mid_pat AS u_communityId, 
        u.IsAnonymous AS u_isAnonymous, 
        u.AnonymousName AS u_anonymousName,
        COALESCE(u.OnlineStatus, 1) AS u_onlineStatus,
        u.OnlineStatusText AS u_onlineStatusText,
        u.LastPing AS u_lastPing,
        u.Email AS u_email,
        u.is_activated
    FROM dbo.pat_note s
    JOIN @trtper us
        ON s.pid = us.pid
    JOIN dbo.pat_mu_us u
        ON u.[UID] = us.sid
        AND u.dispatched = 1
        AND u.[st] = 'ADD'
    JOIN Objs t
        ON t.object_guid = s.Oid
    CROSS APPLY dbo.pat_per_check(us.sid, t.rs_g, 1) p
    WHERE s.communityid = @mid_pat
        AND p.has_perms = 1;
END
```

Need to make it bit faster. Any help would be much appreciated or please tell me step I should check from DB side.

Comment: Start by looking at an execution plan.  What nodes are taking the most time?

Comment: Add ``Primary Key`` to both ``@trtnum`` and ``@trtper`` tables

Comment: How many rows are in `dbo.pat_note`? It is hit several times in multiple statements, all involving a new filter on `communityid = @mid_pat`, which is potentially inefficient. The whole thing strikes me as something that could be better structured. Also, are there appropriate indexes on all tables (including, as IgorM points out, your table variables, but also including the actual base tables)?

Comment: Thank you Robert , IgorM and Steve . Really appreciate

Comment: Hi @steve This is a production Environment with about 800-900 calls per seconds . Of course not only for this process but in general . For above table i have primary key and 3-4 other non-clustered indexes , which are properly fragmented .

Answer (score 0):

Try using temporary tables instead table  variables, because table variables can not be part of parallel operations and the engine does not have good statistics about then. Also, materialized your input user-defined type variable in temporary table, too.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Patinet_Model]
    @mid_pat UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @m_tblpat dbo.GuidList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #trtnum  
    ( 
        pid INT NOT NULL,
        Oid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE(sid, Oid)
    );

    CREATE TABLE #trtper 
    ( 
        pid INT NOT NULL,
        Oid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        patgusBIT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE(sid, Oid)
    );

    CREATE TABLE #buffer
    (
        item UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    )

    INSERT INTO #buffer
    SELECT item
    FROM @m_tblpat;

    WITH Sbb AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ug.[smid] ORDER BY aa.vnum) AS rownumber,
            aa.pid, 
            aa.Oid,
            ug.[smid] as sid
        FROM 
            dbo.pat_note aa
        JOIN 
            dbo.[pat_note] ug ON aa.GroupId = ug.[group_id]
                              AND ug.[is_hidden] = 0
        JOIN 
            #buffer cc ON aa.Oid = cc.item
        WHERE 
            aa.communityid = @mid_pat
    )
    INSERT INTO #trtnum (pid, Oid, sid)
        SELECT pid, Oid,  sid
        FROM Sbb
        WHERE rownumber = 1;

    INSERT INTO #trtper (pid, Oid, sid, patgusBIT)
        SELECT 
            aa.pid, aa.Oid, aa.sid, 
            CASE WHEN ee.sid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM 
            dbo.pat_note aa
        JOIN 
            #buffer dd ON aa.Oid = dd.item
                         AND aa.sid IS NOT NULL
        LEFT JOIN 
            #trtnum ee ON aa.sid = ee.sid AND aa.Oid = ee.Oid
        WHERE 
            aa.communityid = @mid_pat;


    INSERT INTO #trtper (pid, Oid, sid, patgusBIT)
        SELECT pid, Oid, sid, 0 AS patgusBIT
        FROM #trtnum ff
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #trtper WHERE sid = ff.sid AND Oid = ff.Oid);

    WITH CTEA AS
    (
        SELECT
            pkOid AS OG,
            s_g
        FROM ct.oj o
        JOIN #buffer t
            ON o.pkOid = t.item
    )
    SELECT 
        s.pid, 
        s.Oid, 
        s.vnum, 
        s.sid, 
        s.GroupID,
        s.communityid,
        s.Dt_Created as createddate,
        s.[Dt_Modified] as modifieddate,
        us.sid as groupsbb_sid, 
        us.overridesGroupSbbscription,
        u.[User_ID] AS u_sid, 
        u.UserNamespace AS u_namespace, 
        u.FName AS u_fname, 
        u.LName AS u_lname, 
        u.StatusText AS u_statusText, 
        u.StatusUpdated AS u_statusUpdated, 
        u.IMAGE AS u_hasImage, 
        isImageShared AS u_isImageShared, 
        u.Status AS u_status,
        GETDATE() AS u_lastvisit, 
        @mid_pat AS u_communityId, 
        u.IsAnonymous AS u_isAnonymous, 
        u.AnonymousName AS u_anonymousName,
        COALESCE(u.OnlineStatus, 1) AS u_onlineStatus,
        u.OnlineStatusText AS u_onlineStatusText,
        u.LastPing AS u_lastPing,
        u.Email AS u_email,
        u.is_activated
    FROM dbo.pat_note s
    JOIN #trtper us
        ON s.pid = us.pid
    JOIN dbo.pat_mu_us u
        ON u.[UID] = us.sid
        AND u.dispatched = 1
        AND u.[st] = 'ADD'
    JOIN Objs t
        ON t.object_guid = s.Oid
    CROSS APPLY dbo.pat_per_check(us.sid, t.rs_g, 1) p
    WHERE s.communityid = @mid_pat
        AND p.has_perms = 1;
END
```

One step further - materialize the common table expression in temporary tables, too. Sometimes CTE lead to bad execution plans, because of statements being to complex and engine execution the CTE code [multiple times](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32642629-t-sql-common-table-expression-materialize-option) (vote here if you want).

If this is not enough, we need to see what indexes you have on the tables.

Comment: Hi @gotqn Thank you so much for your answer , i will try it soon , but i have multiple indexes on my permanent tables including primary keys . there is not a large data in tables but server is bit busy